# Petición de imagen HTTP en ImageView de Android

Tags: android, web, layout

Estoy tratando que mediante una dirección web me descargue una imagen y que me la acople en un `layout`. Por ejemplo si quiero obtener [esta imagen](https://www.google.es/images/branding/googleg/1x/googleg_standard_color_128dp.png) y que a su vez la acople en un `layout`.

Código *XML*:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/graphLinearLayout"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/activityStockLinearLayout"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/graphImageView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="243dp"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/graph" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Código *Java*:

```
public class intelActivity extends FragmentActivity {

    /**
     * The pager widget, which handles animation and allows swiping horizontally
     * to access previous and next pages.
     */
    ViewPager pager = null;

    /**
     * The pager adapter, which provides the pages to the view pager widget.
     */
    MyFragmentPagerAdapter pagerAdapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_intel);

        // StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();

        //StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);


        ImageView graph = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.graphImageView);
        //graph.setImageResource(R.drawable.graph);

        Picasso.with(this).load("http://chart.finance.yahoo.com/z?s=GOOG").into(graph);

        // Instantiate a ViewPager
        this.pager = (ViewPager) this.findViewById(R.id.viewPager);

        // Create an adapter with the fragments we show on the ViewPager
        MyFragmentPagerAdapter adapter = new MyFragmentPagerAdapter(
                getSupportFragmentManager());
        adapter.addFragment(ScreenSlidePageFragment.newInstance(getResources()
                .getColor(R.color.positivo), 0));
        adapter.addFragment(ScreenSlidePageFragment.newInstance(getResources()
                .getColor(R.color.negativo), 1));
        adapter.addFragment(ScreenSlidePageFragment.newInstance(getResources()
                .getColor(R.color.positivo), 2));
        adapter.addFragment(ScreenSlidePageFragment.newInstance(getResources()
                .getColor(R.color.negativo), 3));
        adapter.addFragment(ScreenSlidePageFragment.newInstance(getResources()
                .getColor(R.color.positivo), 4));
        this.pager.setAdapter(adapter);

        new Thread()
        {
            public void run()
            {

                    while (true) {
                        try {
                        Thread.sleep(3000);
                            Stock stock = null;
                            try {
                                stock = YahooFinance.get("bz=f");
                            } catch (IOException e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }

                            BigDecimal PRUEBA = stock.getQuote().getChange();
                            BigDecimal price = stock.getQuote().getPrice();
                            BigDecimal change = stock.getQuote().getChangeInPercent();
                            BigDecimal peg = stock.getStats().getPeg();
                            BigDecimal dividend = stock.getDividend().getAnnualYieldPercent();

                            System.out.println(price);
                            System.out.println("----------------------------------");
                           // stock.print();

                    }
                catch(Exception ex)
                    {
                    }
                }
            }    
        }.start();
    }
}
```

Comment: y cual es el código? que problema tienes?

Comment: Agrega el codigo java donde haces la peticion de la imagen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Utiliza la librería Piccaso es muy útil para ello. Te adjunto un ejemplo de como sería.

Context -> Contexto de la actividad. 
Load -> Cargas la url de dicha imagen.
Into - > Colocas tu vista en este caso el imageView.

¡¡ IMPORTANTE: Que no se te pase colocar los permisos de internet !!

```
Picasso.with(context).load("http://i.imgur.com/DvpvklR.png").into(imageView);
```

[Información de la misma](http://square.github.io/picasso/)

Comment: Estoy tartando de descargar esta imagen y no me carga me temo que es por que en el link no esta la terminacion .png. Lo que pasa esq ayadiendosela tampoco carga la imagen. He probado con otras imagenes y si descarga y me las pinta en pantalla. Este es el enlace https://chart.finance.yahoo.com/z?s=GOOG

Comment: Picasso.with(context).load(R.drawable.drawableName).into(imageView); Si la tienes descargada en tu Drawable como comentas.

Comment: No la tengo en drawable, lo que me pasa es que no consigo descargar la imagen del enlace que te adjunte arriba. Este es el bloque que de codigo que tengo:  ** ImageView graph = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.graphImageView);
        Picasso.with(this).load("http://chart.finance.yahoo.com/z?s=GOOG").into(graph); ** @Saantty

Comment: El problema como comentabas es que no lo detecta como imagen entonces no la carga.

Comment: y hay alguna manera de solventar esto? ya que pinchando en el enlace que te he adjuntado el único elemento que devuelve es una imagen de formato .png

Comment: Muéstrame tu código donde introduces la imagen. Sino descargarte la imagen y subela a cualquier repositorio de imágenes para obtenerla desde ahí.

Comment: La idea que tenia en mente era la de introducir dentro del hilo nuevas peticiones de la imagen cada X tiempo. Ya que en este momento la bolsa se encuentra cerrada pero cuando esta abierta, Yahoo modifica la imagen y cada vez que se hace una petición la imagen se actualiza con los nuevos valores. Por eso la idea de subirlo a un repositorio no puedo hacerla ya que seria lo mismo que tener una imagen fija en la carpeta drawables

Comment: Parece que todo esta correcto debería de aparecer dicha imagen, tal vez Piccaso no reconozca dicha URL como una imagen..

Answer (score 1):

No hay forma de incluir como tal la imagen en el layout.xml así que yo me decantaría por definirlo de esta forma:

```
URL url = new URL("https://www.google.es/images/branding/googleg/1x/googleg_standard_color_128dp.png");
Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(url.openConnection().getInputStream());
imageView.setImageBitmap(bmp);
```

Comment: y por que las librerias que me comentan me impide hacer lo que quiero hacer??

Comment: @EduardoMéndez no conozco las librerias que responden otros usuarios, yo me refiero a que sin librerias el método es ese, si prefieres usar alguna libreria de las que responden, adelante, pueden servir.

Comment: oquei hare las pruebas segun pueda gracias por la info ;D

Answer (score 1):

Te recomiendo Picasso o Glide (https://github.com/bumptech/glide).
Cada uno tiene sus ventajas y desventajas pero funcionan muy bien para eso que quieres hacer.

Por supuesto lo que dice @Saantty que agregues los permisos al manifest para acceso a internet

Answer (score 1):

Exactamente lo que te dice el compañero @Saantty, ademas el permiso de internet deberas de añadirlo en el Manifiesto (AndroidManifest.xml) en sus primeras lineas, pega esto:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```